The differential equation cannot be solved

Let $\Omega = (0, 1) \times (0, 1)$ (a "square"), $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2)^T \in \Omega$, $\Gamma = \partial \Omega$,
$$
\Omega_c \subseteq \Omega \left( \Omega_c = (0, 1) \times (0, \frac{1}{2}) \right) - \text{"left half"},
$$
$$
\Omega_{ob} \subseteq \Omega \text{ (consider the following options: } \Omega_{ob} = \Omega, \Omega_{ob} = \Omega_c, \Omega_{ob} = (0, 1) \times (\frac{1}{2}, 1)) - \text{"right half"}).
$$
$$
-\operatorname{div}(\mu \nabla \Phi) + b \Phi = f + m_c u \quad \text{in } \Omega,
$$
$$
\Phi = 0 \quad \text{on } \Gamma,
$$
$$
\Phi = \Phi_{obs} \quad \text{in } \Omega_{ob},
$$
where $f, \Phi_{obs}$ are given, $\mu = \text{const} > 0, b = \text{const} > 0, m_c$ is the characteristic function of $\Omega_c \left( m_c = 1 \text{ if } \vec{x} \in \Omega_c, m_c = 0 \text{ if } \vec{x} \in \Gamma \backslash \Omega_c \right)$. Find $\Phi$ and $u$

The differential equation looks like $-\mu \Delta \Phi + b \Phi = f(x, y)$ on one half and like $-\mu \Delta \Phi + b \Phi = f(x, y) + u(x, y)$ on the other half. Moreover, $\Phi$ on half of the square equals some specific unknown function. But what if this specific function does not satisfy the differential equation? We do not know the form of either this specific function (as I understand, this relates to physics, and "obs" means "observable") or the function $f(x, y)$. Numerical solution without this information is definitely not possible, and for the analytical solution, there is no guarantee of compatibility...
Either I did not understand the task, or there is really something missing in the task
